# Keytool error importing SSL certificate into J9 keystore

Tags: java, ssl, windows-mobile-6.5, j9, maximo

We trying to import main certificate into keystore caserts J9 mobile VM. The exception:

```
keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
```

Certificates algorithm is sha2-256 with 2048 bit key (or 4096 bit in production environment).

We can't change private certificate. The only VM we can run Maximo Mobile on Windows Mobile 6.5 is J9. We tried J9 2.2 and J9 2.4. We have 300 expensive Win Mobile devices bought by our client and we stuck. Please help us.

**More Info**

[image: Architecture]

Specs:

Server OS - Windows Server 2003 5.2 build 3790 Service Pack 2
Web Server - IBM HTTP Server 7.0.13
App Server - Websphere Application Server 6.1.0.23
Mobile Device M3 Orange (Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional, CE OS 5.2.21840 ,build 21480.5.0.60)
IBM J9 VM from Maximo Mobile 7.5.0

IBM Maximo
Service Desk Integration MEA 7.2.1.00 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7200-03 SRM Service Request Management 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-07 IMBot SRM Service Desk 7.2.0.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7200-03 SRM Service Desk Content - Classification 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-03 SRM Service Desk Content - Best Practices 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-10 IBM Tivoli Common Process Components 7.2.1.0 Build 201008131846 DB Build V7210-07 SRM Service Desk Content - Best Practice Users 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-03 SRM Service Desk 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-24 SRM Screen Capturer 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-01 IBM Maximo Project Adaptor 7.1.1.02 Build 14 DB Build V7110-02 SRM Problem Management 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-05 ISM Content Installer 7.2.1.0 Build 201008100736 DB Build V7210-04 SRM Solution 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-07 SRM Incident Management 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-06 SRM SLA Hold 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-03 SRM Service Catalog Base 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-13 Advanced Workflow Components 7.2.1.0 Build 201008121716 DB Build V7210-04 Mobile 7.1.1.0 Build 20091209-0657 DB Build V7110-24 SRM Search 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-05 Maximo Unit Test Tool 7.1.0.0 Build BUILD DB Build V7100-01 SRM Survey Management 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-04 Base Services 7.1.1.8 Build 20110105-1024 DB Build V7118-37 SRM Service Catalog Content 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-09 SRM Self Service Center 7.2.1.0 Build 201008192131 DB Build V7210-01 IBM Maximo for Service Provider 7.1.1.2 Build 20100408-1049 DB Build V7122-06 HFDB Build HF7122-06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the way to fix this.

1. Download [this library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) for JDK 1.4
2. Put it in the folder JAVA_HOME\lib\jclFoundation11\ext\
3. Expand providers list by editing the file JAVA_HOME\lib\security\java.security

   ```
   security.provider.4=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
   ```