# Certificate signature validation failed

Tags: java, validation, amazon-web-services, ssl

My website is hosted on Amazon. It is built on the microsoft version of java 1.4.2_13. I noticed emails were not going out. I had not made any changes to the code. I found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/use-sha256.html) document on amazon's site and followed their directions to find out that our java environment did not pass the test. So, I imported the new ssl root certificate. I can verify that it is in the keystore, but I get the following error message when I run their shaTest and emails are still not being sent. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at ShaTest.main(ShaTest.java:11)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 Signature not available
    at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take care when adding code to make sure it's formatted correctly as a code block. Four spaces are required at the beginning of ever line to place code in a code block. Simplest is to select all the code then click the "Code" button in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks Cindy! Yes, I'm new here.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365209/java-and-ssl-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception) helps. Generally speaking, it means that the installed version of Java lacks libraries. Bouncycastle or something alike not included, perhaps?

Comment: Can you turn on debugging and post the result here? For Sun's JVM, you can turn on debugging by passing the java executable the option -Djavax.net.debug=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java itself got SHA256 support in 1.4.2, but the Microsoft Java may not- especially because it's been discontinued for a long time. [You might be able to use bouncycastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487988/send-mail-fails-because-of-ssl-certificate-how-to-add-new-certificate-or-check).

Note Java 1.4 came out in **2002**. That's 14 years ago. That should be a huge red flag; I wouldn't run that on any machine connected to the Internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with this version of java. I will look at bouncycastle to see if I can use it. Was there anything worth paying attention to in the debug output I posted. Sorry, I'm new to SSL.

Comment: NoSuchAlgorithm is interesting, you might find a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435654/keytool-error-importing-ssl-certificate-into-j9-keystore). Basically security is evolving, even java7 isn't capable of supporting some of the modern TLS-only policies.