# error.sun.security.validator.validatorexception: Certificate signature algorithm disabled

Tags: java, validation, security

In the recent Java update of 1.8.0_151, I am starting to get an exception when I use a library that let's you push documents to Google Drive

error.sun.security.validator.validatorexception: Certificate signature algorithm disabled

Regardless of the code used to produce it, what does this exception mean? Did anyone face it and know a work around for it? It never happened in any previous Java version

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092318/certificate-signature-validation-failed

Comment: That's a different issue. 1) It talks about handshake exception which does not appear in the error above. 2) It talks about Java 1.4 which the answer says "should update".  This error just started appearing in the update that happened last month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have the stacktrace but **probably** you skipped 14x and the code is using HTTPS or other TLS to some Google (or perhaps other?) **server with a SHA1-signed cert in its chain**, because 141 up disable such certs if default trusted which Google is; see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u141-relnotes-3720385.html#NewFeature . Incidentally 151 was 3 months ago and 141 5 months ago -- and SHA1 certs for public TLS have been officially prohibited for almost 3 *years* and [SHA1 was actually broken for collision almost a year ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152142/what-are-the-implications-of-a-sha-1-collision-being-found).

If that is indeed the problem, you can work around it by editing `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` in `JRE/lib/security/java.security` to remove this item, but it's probably a better solution to look for a server that uses an up-to-date certificate chain. If the library doesn't expose what server(s) it's talking to when this occurs, you could [turn on tracing per JSSERefGuide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) (although this produces a *lot* of cruft to sort through) or depending on platform and environment (which you didn't identify) you may have other network monitoring or tracing tools to use.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very helpful answer